# TemplateSyntaxError 'staticfiles' no es una biblioteca de etiquetas válida '

Tags: python-3.x, django

Tengo un problema con el {% load staticfiles %} y el{% load static %} ya lei e intente de todo, pero siguen sigo teniendo error..
estuve leyendo las respuestas pero siguen sin aparecerme los efectos de mi carpeta 'static' donde guardo los .css, alguien que pueda ayudarme por favor.. a continuacion mi base.py, local.py y settings.py..

mi local.py, en el local.py agregue el STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'statics'] y si me carga la pagina html solo que no los colores que le agrego.

```
from .base import *
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_empleado',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'leonleon1911',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'statics']
```

mi settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for empleado project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.5.
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'empleado.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'empleado.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

mi base.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes podrias decirme cuales son las rutas de tus archivos ya que aveces puede ser que no estés poniendo la ruta correcta

Answer (score 0):

El uso de los ficheros STATIC y MEDIA es un tanto complicado cuando estás empezando en Django.

El proceso de hecho debería ser simple:

1. Crear la carpeta en el directorio del proyecto Django
2. Definir dónde está esa carpeta

Esa carpeta puede diferir en los entornos de desarrollo y producción, complicando aún más el asunto.

### En desarrollo

```
#settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'  #puedes cambiarse, solo altera la URL que genera Django
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR / '_static'] #o el nombre de tu directorio
```

### En producción

Hay que añadir el directorio en el cual se van a concentrar todos los archivos STATIC de todas las aplicaciones (mediante `collectstatic`):

```
#settings.py

STATIC_ROOT = 'ruta-del-directorio-en-el-servidor'
```

Además, tienes que asegurarte de que `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` está incluida en `INSTALLED_APPS`

### Cuando todo eso está correcto y todavía falla

En tu pregunta veo que el directorio definido en los ficheros local y de desarrollo no son el mismo:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'statics'] # con S final
```

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] # sin S final
```

Comprueba que no sea ese gazapo el que está confundiendo todo.

Espero te sea útil.